# Error with iframe Vue.js don't show anything

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe, vue-component

Good day everyone, I've the following problem, I'm developing a website in Vue.js, the error occurs that I want to implement a specific news section in my website, when using the iframe component I get this error:

```
cryptocurrency-news:1 Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'http://localhost:8080' from frame with URL 'https://www.reference-website.com/news/cryptocurrency-news'. The frame attempting navigation is targeting its top-level window, but is neither same-origin with its target nor has it received a user gesture. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5851021045661696


Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to
```

The section of my code is simple, since according to documentation it should not present failures

```
<template>

<iframe src="https://reference-website.com/news/cryptocurrency-news" width="900" height="700"></iframe>

</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: 'News'
}
</script>
```

I do not understand why the error is due, if you can guide me, I appreciate the help.